# How can I setup blender for texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

I want to create hand painted textures for my game assets which I will then use in unity game engine. What render engine should I use and what setting do I need to turn on/off for the best result? I’m just worried about lighting mostly because i don’t want my textures to be influenced by extra lights in blender.

Comment: You could just paint your texture on the objects using Flat in the screen overlays instead of using the lights, turning off shadow and cavity is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

**Texture Painting**

If you paint a diffuse map, lights don't really matter that much. You don't render anything, so nothing but the color of your choice influences the texture.

Any light setup might only influence, how you perceive the colors.

**Lights (for baking):**

Delete all lights, you won't need them. Go to the World Properties Tab and change the Background Color to white.

[image: World Settings]

**Material Setup (for painting):**

Go to the Shader Editor, create a new material and delete the Principled BSDF. Create a new Image Texture and connect it to an Emission Node (with Node Wrangler installed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>) to the Material Output.

[image: Material Settings]

**Render Engine:**

If you only want to paint textures and you don't intend to bake additional maps (normal, AO, etc.) the Render Engine doesn't really matter. If you do want to bake additional maps, Cycles is the only option, since baking is not possible in Eevee (yet).

Since you paint in Material Preview, you might want to change the HDRi Image in the Studio Lights setup to a more neutral one* and set the Background Visibility to zero.

[image: Studio Lights HDRi]

- hdrihaven.com has some nice outdoor HDRis with overcast sky that deliver a nice flat shading. They still influence your color perception, though...

Comment: Thankyou ! How can I install the node wrangler ?

Comment: Is node wrangler necessary?

Comment: @ulus - no, it's not necessary, but it helps a lot, once you start using nodes regularly.